# Creating fixed position for non scrolling is messing up div location on page

Tags: html, css, scroll

Hello I am having a problem that when I make my top area non scroll able the area almost completely disappears.

[Before Fixed Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp7pI.png)

html for header

```
<section id="header">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="top-nav">
                        <li>
                <a href="#" class="choose-language" data-toggle="popover" id="languageChooser" data-original-title="" title="">
                    English
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <div id="languageChooserContent" class="hidden">
                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=arabic">العربية</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=azerbaijani">Azerbaijani</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=catalan">Català</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=chinese">中文</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=croatian">Hrvatski</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=czech">Čeština</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=danish">Dansk</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=dutch">Nederlands</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=english">English</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=estonian">Estonian</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=farsi">Persian</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=french">Français</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=german">Deutsch</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=hebrew">עברית</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=hungarian">Magyar</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=italian">Italiano</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=macedonian">Macedonian</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=norwegian">Norwegian</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=portuguese-br">Português</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=portuguese-pt">Português</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=romanian">Română</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=russian">Русский</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=spanish">Español</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=swedish">Svenska</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=turkish">Türkçe</a>
                            </li>
                                                        <li>
                                <a href="/index.php?language=ukranian">Українська</a>
                            </li>
                                                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
                                    <li>
                <a href="/clientarea.php">Login</a>
            </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/register.php">Register</a>
                </li>
                            <li class="primary-action">
                <a href="/cart.php?a=view" class="btn">
                    View Cart
                </a>
            </li>
                            </ul>

                <a href="/index.php" class="logo"><img src="/assets/img/logo.png" alt="WebKing Web Services"></a>

</div>
</section>
```

html for navbar
    
    
        
            
            
                
                    Toggle navigation

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-nav">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li menuitemname="Home" class="" id="Primary_Navbar-Home">
    <a href="/index.php">
                    Home
                            </a>
        </li>
<li menuitemname="Store" class="dropdown" id="Primary_Navbar-Store">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Store
                    &nbsp;<b class="caret"></b>        </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li menuitemname="Browse Products Services" id="Primary_Navbar-Store-Browse_Products_Services">
                <a href="/cart.php">
                                            Browse All
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Shop Divider 1" class="nav-divider" id="Primary_Navbar-Store-Shop_Divider_1">
                <a href="">
                                            -----
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Select Your Perfect Plan" id="Primary_Navbar-Store-Select_Your_Perfect_Plan">
                <a href="/cart.php?gid=1">
                                            Select Your Perfect Plan
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="symantec" id="Primary_Navbar-Store-symantec">
                <a href="/index.php?rp=/store/ssl-certificates">
                                            SSL Certificates
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Shop Divider 2" class="nav-divider" id="Primary_Navbar-Store-Shop_Divider_2">
                <a href="">
                                            -----
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Register a New Domain" id="Primary_Navbar-Store-Register_a_New_Domain">
                <a href="/cart.php?a=add&amp;domain=register">
                                            Register a New Domain
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Transfer a Domain to Us" id="Primary_Navbar-Store-Transfer_a_Domain_to_Us">
                <a href="/cart.php?a=add&amp;domain=transfer">
                                            Transfer Domains to Us
                                        </a>
            </li>
                    </ul>
        </li>
<li menuitemname="Announcements" class="" id="Primary_Navbar-Announcements">
    <a href="/index.php?rp=/announcements">
                    Announcements
                            </a>
        </li>
<li menuitemname="Knowledgebase" class="" id="Primary_Navbar-Knowledgebase">
    <a href="/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase">
                    Knowledgebase
                            </a>
        </li>
<li menuitemname="Network Status" class="" id="Primary_Navbar-Network_Status">
    <a href="/serverstatus.php">
                    Network Status
                            </a>
        </li>
<li menuitemname="Contact Us" class="" id="Primary_Navbar-Contact_Us">
    <a href="/contact.php">
                    Contact Us
                            </a>
        </li>

            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li menuitemname="Account" class="dropdown" id="Secondary_Navbar-Account">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Account
                    &nbsp;<b class="caret"></b>        </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li menuitemname="Login" id="Secondary_Navbar-Account-Login">
                <a href="/clientarea.php">
                                            Login
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Register" id="Secondary_Navbar-Account-Register">
                <a href="/register.php">
                                            Register
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Divider" class="nav-divider" id="Secondary_Navbar-Account-Divider">
                <a href="">
                                            -----
                                        </a>
            </li>
                        <li menuitemname="Forgot Password?" id="Secondary_Navbar-Account-Forgot_Password?">
                <a href="/pwreset.php">
                                            Forgot Password?
                                        </a>
            </li>
                    </ul>
        </li>

            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

</section>
```

Code:

```
section#header {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

Now when I add the position fixed and try to make it uncontrollable the white part and logo area no longer scroll however before i even begin to scroll my menu bar is pushed up and out of position.

[Picture now fixed you can see the menu bar has changed its location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7yvi.png) Here is the new code

```
section#header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

This is not a z-index issue as this is happening before i even scroll down the page.

I have been stuck for days I would really be grateful for any help.

UPDATE: Okay I have the fixed menu where it is supposed to be but now I am having this issue with every page and I have no idea why every div and section has moved up as if the header doesnt exist. mind you this is before any scrolling begin. Please feel free to visit webking.com and navigate to any page to see what I mean.

[As you can see a huge mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYahL.png)

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention this is not a z-index issue, The area you are looking at is before i even attempt to scroll,

Comment: Without the matching HTML for your CSS no one can answer this question.

Comment: Just added html sorry about that

Comment: Add a margin-top with height of the fixed header to the rest of the elements.

Comment: @Shim-Sao the problem with this solution is now I would have to adjust every section that isn't fixed. it changes the dynamic of all the other pages on the website. as seen here 

https://www.webking.com/scroll3.png

Comment: @Shim-Sao the problem with this solution is now I would have to adjust every section that isn't fixed. it changes the dynamic of all the other pages on the website. as seen here. Is there a way to add space underneath to make spacing dynamically to anything below header?

Comment: You can use responsive Media Query : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: You want to fix header to what ? If you fixed it, it will stay at the same position and it doesn't count for others elements, that explain margin trick. With Media Query, you can set different margin according to the height changes of the header.

Comment: To be sure I well understand : You want blue menu stays to the top and the image logo below.

Comment: @Shim-Sao I have media query setup for mobile that is not the issue. WHat I am trying to explain is that everytime i used a fixed position the section or div below gets pushed up as if the header no longer existed in the space so the next section just moves itself in its place,

Comment: @Shim-Sao if you go to https://www.webking.com/ you will see the logo area with login and the menu below are fixed which is what I want but as a result now every section and div has moved itself up like 30-40px and  now is cut off before you even start to scroll, If you notice the first picture i posted the text where the domain search is supposed to be is now cut off. I understand I can change height in every div but to do that for every page that has this header would be rather tedious. Feel free to nav other pages to see what I mean about everything being cut off.

Comment: I'm writing a solution

Answer (score 0):

So here is my last corrections :

1st step fix the header :

```
section#header {
    position: fixed; /* We want the header fixed at top */
    z-index: 1000; /* We want header over other elements when scrolling */
    /* margin: -5px 0 0 0; */ /* Remove seems not needed */
    height: 60px; /* We should fix the header height */
    width: 100%; /* header will take all available width */
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

2nd step fix the menu :

```
section#main-menu {
        /* margin: 60px auto 0; */ /* It is not the place for the marin-top. We don't need this */
        position: fixed; /* We want the menu fixed at top */
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #006687;
        top: 60px; /* We want menu above the header so we shift the menu of the height of the header */
        z-index: 1000; /* We want menu over other elements when scrolling */
}
```

3rd step correction of the content :

Here, I don't understand why (maybe need more investigations) but
the browser take the `margin-top` of the `section#main-body` and
apply it to the header. It's is not what we want and it's here we
will fix it with this :

We will add and apply the margin-top trick to the
`.container` inside the `section#main-body`
like this :

```
section#main-body .container {
    margin-top: 100px; /* header : 60 + menu : 40 */
}
```

Comment: The menu is where it needs to be now but the logo section is way off and is no longer fixed. I tried adding fixed to it and everything gets even more messed up. However I feel like its getting a lot closer.

webking.com as you see now

Comment: I have commented all the margin on the menu for the test. There is just some things to adjust and make dynamic when the menu change. You have the solution I think ;)

Comment: If you could take one more look. If I do not put position:fixed for section#header all is the right place expect the section header now scrolls. here are the pictures

[link] webking.com/unfixed1.png
[link] webking.com/unfixed2.png

so now If I add position:fixed to section#header all hell breaks lose as seen below.

[link](http://webking.com/fixed.png)

Comment: Sorry I don't add this in the response but yes, you should put position fix on the header and on the menu.

Comment: I did that and this is what happens. [link](http://webking.com/fixed.png)

Comment: You don't follow my instructions. section#home-banner => margin-top : header + menu heights (around 100px when I have test). You add strange padding.

Comment: I apologize I guess I am not understanding. If you are willing can you shoot me an email to admin [at] webking [dot] com and I can either throw you some cash if you can work with me to fix this solution or give you unlimited hosting for life. Thank You

Comment: I'm searching for job at now. I can fix it quickly tomorrow I think, it's very late for me (France). I will send you a mail, no problem.

Comment: Thank you I am awaiting your email. Have a nice night.

Comment: hey just checking in I never heard back from you. Do you think you can still help? Thank you again

Comment: I had send an email yesterday. you did not receive it !?